# Why do I need to set the lambda capture?

Tags: c++11, lambda

I have not much experience in using lambda's - I was hoping someone could explain what I did below in 'layman's terms' (if possible).

I have a `std::vector` with a number of objects (or none). Each object has an id. I want to place the object with the id I am interested in at the back of the vector.

I did that like so

```
std::vector<my_ob> l_obs;

[...] // populate the vector

auto l_elem = std::find_if(l_obs.rbegin(), 
  l_obs.rend(), [](my_ob const& ob){ return ob.mv_id == 8;});

if(l_elem-l_obs.rbegin())
  std::iter_swap(l_elem, l_obs.rbegin());
```

I am using a reverse iterator as I expect the match to already be at the back of the vector in most cases.

The above worked fine, until I moved it into a method and instead of trying to find '8', I wanted to find a value passed as a `const int` parameter. The compiler told me that the parameter I used was not captured, and that the lambda had no capture default. So I changed the lambda to

```
[=](my_ob const& ob){ return ob.mv_id == _arg;}
```

and this all seems to work now.

Why was this = sign needed?

Comment: Perhaps [this lambda expression reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) might help?

Comment: `std::iter_swap` -- that line is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda expressions produce *closure* objects, which are *function objects* (similar to a `struct` with an overloaded `operator()`).

In order for closures to use variables in the outer scope, they must know how: either by copying the variable into the closure itself, or by referring to it.

---

Writing

```
[=](my_ob const& ob){ return ob.mv_id == _arg;}
```

is equivalent to

```
[_arg](my_ob const& ob){ return ob.mv_id == _arg;}
```

which roughly desugars to

```
struct LAMBDA 
{
    int _arg;
    LAMBDA(int arg) : _arg{arg} { }

    auto operator()(my_ob const& ob) const { return ob.mv_id == _arg; }
};
```

---

As you can see, `_arg` needs to be available in the scope of the generated `LAMBDA` function object, so it needs to be a data member of the closure.

When you were using a literal, no captures were needed as the generated closure looked like:

```
struct LAMBDA 
{
    auto operator()(my_ob const& ob) const { return ob.mv_id == 5; }
};
```

Comment: You might want to add an example for referencing as well (i.e. `[&]`)